# Backbone and jquerymobile:can't disable routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm triyng to disable jquerymobile's rounting but appear error loading page and the url is no catched by backbone.I've disabled all parameters of jqeurymobile as read on some tutorial.

Here where disable jquerymobile:

```
       require.config({
     paths: {
    jQuery: '../libs/jquery/jquery-loader',
    jQueryMobile: '../libs/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-loader',
    underscore: '../libs/underscore/underscore-loader',
    Backbone: '../libs/backbone/backbone-loader',
    order: '../libs/require/order-1.0.5',
    text: '../libs/require/text-1.0.6',
    async: '../libs/require/async',
    //PhoneGap: '../libs/phonegap/phonegap-loader',
    Handlebars: '../libs/handlebars/Handlebars',
    templates: '../templates'
        }
        });

         require(['order!jQuery'], function($) {

      // jQueryMobile configuration
       $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
    $.mobile.pageContainer = $("body");

    // Remove page from DOM when it's being replaced, otherwise the DOM will contain    
    all of them
    $('div[data-role="page"]').on('pagehide', function(event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
     });

     // We launch the App
       // jQueryMobile is referenced in order to start its initialization
      require(['underscore', 'Backbone', 'router', 'jQueryMobile'], function(_,  
       Backbone, AppRouter, jQueryMobile) {



    document.addEventListener("deviceready", run, false);
     run();

    function run() {

        var sync = Backbone.sync;
      Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
      options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'niI               
      BCf78Rfe1wu**yQWUrr6A3yyhex3M');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'l4CgjESBwPYA**3Pq1V1LKHTvuhQj');
          };



        sync(method, model, options);

      },

        app = new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();

        Parse.$ = jQuery;


       Parse.initialize("niIBCf***7tbnyQWUrr6A3yyhex3M",
               "HD4bsMvPh3T*YvT1MIdOh2GR");

          }
        })
         });
```

and here where url is declared:

```
         <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/insert" data-icon="home"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="search"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /navbar -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am have been having the same problem! At first I thought it might be because all of the examples I've seen (jquerymobile site & addy osmain's site) are using older versions of jqm and I thought maybe the new version was buggy.

But going back over the code I see where my problem was: you have be careful to make your bind of "mobile init" BEFORE jquerymobile is required.

In the jqm docs, you can see the basic principle:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/

Here's my working code (located in my requireJS bootstrap app.js):

```
// Includes File Dependencies
require(
    ['require', 'backbone', 'jquery', 'underscore' ],
    function( require, Backbone, $, _ ) {
        // framework loaded
        console.log('framework libraries loaded');

        $( document ).on( "mobileinit",
            // Set up the "mobileinit" handler before requiring jQuery Mobile's module
            function() {

                //apply jquery mobile overrides here

                // Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
                $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

                // Prevents all anchor click handling including the addition of active button state and alternate link bluring.
                $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

            }
        );

        require(
                ['require', 'jquerymobile', 'app'], 
                function( require,  Mobile ) {

                    console.log('jq mobile has been loaded...');

                    // when jquery mobile is first ready to go, remove hidden on main container div
                    // if this isn't done, we'll see a flash of unenhanced DOM before jqm can get to it
                    $('#body-container').removeClass('hidden');

                }
        );
    } 
);
```